# Find the residues of branches of form $e^{\frac1{1+\sqrt(z)}}dz$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Find the residues of branches of form $e^{\frac1{1+\sqrt z}}dz$ at $z=1$. How to see that $z=1$ is a pole of this? I don't understand what should I do with root at the denominator. We can write $\sqrt z=exp(\frac12 \ln z)$ but it does not help here.

Comment: There are two branches of $\sqrt{\cdot}$. The one where $\sqrt{1}=1$ and the one where $\sqrt{1}=-1$. Let's compute for the one where $\sqrt{1}=1$. First write $\sqrt{z}=(1+(z-1))^{1/2}$. Apply the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations) to get that $\sqrt{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{1/2}{n}(z-1)^n$. This is analytic at $z=1$ and different from $-1$ at that point. Therefore, when we add $1$, take reciprocal, and exponentiate, the result is analytic. Hence the residue is zero. Now look at the computation on the other branch.

Comment: @blueInk in another branches we got $e^{\frac12}$?